# Oauth2 login using reactjs and discord

Tags: node.js, reactjs, oauth-2.0, discord

I am trying to implement **oauth2** using **reactjs** and **nodejs** but i still didn't find any code sample i will work on can you please share any links with me , Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented oauth2.0 Implicit Grant Flow in React JS(SPA). By going through this [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-javascript).

Or

you can refer to this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IghiKqly-HY&t=1811s).